# Craft 3 upload path on webserver

Tags: craft3, installation

My hoster has i public html folder where all websites are lying. Different Websites are separeted by subfolders. Should i upload all Craft3 installation files to this public html folder and point the webserver to the /web folder?

Or should i upload only the /web folder to my webhoster's public html folder and place all other files ABOVE, like it's explained in the [Craft 2 installation guide](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/installing.html)? 
If yes, how do i configure the craft path in the index.php file?

Thank you very much for a explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only upload the /web folder to the /public_html folder.

All other folders should be one level lower so they're not publicly accessible.

Personally, I'm also wondering why not everything resides in a nice clean /craft folder anymore. Now the craft directories are listed amongst a bunch of other stuff on a lowerlevel directory. It's probably the only one really strange architectural choice. I guess P&T is not using WHM/Cpanel etc.

Anyway: do not upload anything except /web in your public folder.

If you do it like this, the index will work correctly out of the box, since it'll be looking for the /app and all folders one level lower then the /public_html by default.

Comment: That's because the clean way to install Craft is via composer and the composer puts everything into the `vendor`  folder. It's much better the way it is now.

Comment: No it doesn't.... WHM/Cpanel, one of the most popular control pannels, with or without composer, it creates this mess. There's a vendor folder alright, but all the rest is mixed. I find this a very, VERY, poor choice of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in a dedicated craft folder or a private_html folder with composer, but then you have to edit the index.php file a bit to make it work. See [Setup Craft 3 when de craft folder is above public_html on shared hosting](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25504/setup-craft-3-when-de-craft-folder-is-above-public-html-on-shared-hosting)

Comment: didn't work for me. I had to set the path in the index.php file like this: `define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', '../../craft folder above public_html');`

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to insert the full path, avoiding any confusion, like so:

    define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', ('/home/pathToCraftFolder/craft'));